# ZF2 - 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hello I'm trying to run [This Blog Example](http://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html) So i have each and every steps that this tutorial said but now i'm getting this error: After creating Factory Class

> Fatal error: Class Blog\Factory\ListControllerFactory contains 1
>   abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods
>   (Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\zend2test\module\Blog\src\Blog\Factory\ListControllerFactory.php
>   on line 28

Here is my factory class:

```
// Filename: /module/Blog/src/Blog/Factory/ListControllerFactory.php
 namespace Blog\Factory;

 use Blog\Controller\ListController;
 use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
 use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

 class ListControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
 {

    private $serviceLocator;
     /**
      * Create service
      *
      * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
      *
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
     {
         $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
         $postService        = $realServiceLocator->get('Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface');

         return new ListController($postService);
     }
 }
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FactoryInterface](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/master/src/FactoryInterface.php) you are using extends another Interface:

`FactoryInterface extends Factory\FactoryInterface`.

And that [interface](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/blob/master/src/Factory/FactoryInterface.php) declares the `__invoke` method. So for your class to be compliant you need to implement both **createService** and **__invoke**.

Declare also the `__invoke` method. E.g.

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // get your dependency
        $postService = $container->get('Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface');
        // inject it int the constructor
        return new ListController($postService);
    }
```

Also, add the line:

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
```

At the beginning of your file (with your other "use" statements)

Comment: thanks @yivi for answer but after adding **__invoke()** now its giving this ----> `Fatal error: Declaration of Blog\Factory\ListControllerFactory::__invoke() must be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke(Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = NULL) `

Comment: Sorry about that. Try it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132178/discussion-between-shail-paras-and-yivi).